# Spring: Setting BeanFactory in BeanFactoryPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring, factory

I have Greeting Bean:

```
@Component
public class Greeting implements IGreeting {
    private String greeting;
    // setter and getter
}
```

I have `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`:

```
@Component
public class GreetingBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory) throws BeansException {
        BeanDefinition beanDefinition = configurableListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition("greeting");
        beanDefinition.setFactoryBeanName("greetingBeanFactory");
    }
}
```

And I have `BeanFactory`:

```
@Component
public class GreetingBeanFactory extends AbstractFactoryBean<Object> {
    @Override
    public Class<Greeting> getObjectType() {
        return Greeting.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createInstance() throws Exception {
        LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        int hour = currentTime.getHour();
        IGreeting greeting = new Greeting();
        if ((hour >= 7) && (12 > hour)) {
            greeting.setGreeting("morning");
        }else if((hour >= 12) && (18 > hour)) {
            greeting.setGreeting("day");
        }else if((hour >= 18) && (24 > hour)){
            greeting.setGreeting("evening");
        }else if((hour >= 0) && (7 > hour)){
            greeting.setGreeting("night");
        }
        System.out.println("Tuned 'Greeting' by Factory Bean: " + greeting);
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

And Controller:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    IGreeting greeting;

    @RequestMapping("/hello_world")
    public String index() {
        System.out.println("Actual `Greeting` used in application: " + greeting);
        return String.format("Good %s!", greeting.getGreeting());
    }

}
```

I am logging instances and see following:

```
Tuned 'Greeting' by Factory Bean: com.epam.springboot.model.Greeting@514eedd8
Actual `Greeting` used in application: com.epam.springboot.model.Greeting@39c4a65a
```

Why my tuned by `FactoryBean` instance get lost and why I get a new one
in controller? Is it ok architecture at all, is it good example of `FactoryBean` and `FactoryBeanPostProcessor` usage?

Comment: Why on earth do you use this contraption? Remove the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and simply remove `@Component` from your `Greeting` class and just leave the annotation on the `FactoryBean`.

Comment: AFAIK, when component scan happens BeanFactory not consulted to register bean to application context. You may have to implement application context aware to get the context and register the instance in your bean factory